# Is the appendix a vestigial structure in all vertebrates?

Tags: zoology, organs, vestigial

In humans the Appendix is a vestigial organ. Does it serve no apparent purpose in all the vertebrates that have one?

Comment: I don't think the appendix is vestigial in humans.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

[Smith et al. (2009)](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1111/j.1420-9101.2009.01809.x/full) provide a survey of the morphology of the cecal appendix. One current hypothesis is that the appendix provides "safe harbor" for symbiotic gut bacteria. Among mammals, there is a vast array of cecal appendices:

[image: Morphology of the appendix]

In summary:

> A comparative anatomical approach reveals three apparent morphotypes
>   of the cecal appendix, as well as appendix-like structures in some
>   species that lack a true cecal appendix. Cladistic analyses indicate
>   that the appendix has evolved independently at least twice (at least
>   once in diprotodont marsupials and at least once in Euarchontoglires),
>   shows a highly significant (P < 0.0001) phylogenetic signal in its
>   distribution, and has been maintained in mammalian evolution for 80
>   million years or longer.

Answer (score 9):

Aside from humans, it is largely rodents and most notably rabbits that have an appendix.  Therefore, using rabbits as my example:

In rabbits, the appendix is thought to have a key role in the development of the immune system.  Specifically it has been shown experimentally that when neonatal rabbits are given an appendectomy levels of Immunoglobulin A and G (IgA/IgG) fall dramatically. Both these polypeptides are prominent antibodies - IgA plays a key role in mucosal immunity whilst IgGs in humoral immunity.  These effects were localised to the small intestine of the rabbits, however were statistically significant. <sup>1</sup>

*In infants*, the rabbit appendix resembles the chicken bursa and sheep ileal Peyer's patch (both performing similar functions as described above).<sup>2</sup>

This has led to some ongoing research as to whether the human appendix has a similar properties in having function in infants <sup>3</sup>:

> If the human appendix functions as a primary lymphoid organ, it may occur during the first few months of age when the GC T-cell density is low.

---

<sup>1</sup>[Neonatal appendectomy impairs mucosal immunity in rabbits. Cell Immunol. 1997 Nov 25;182(1):29-37](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/9427807)

<sup>2</sup>[The appendix functions as a mammalian bursal equivalent in the developing rabbit. Adv Exp Med Biol. 1994;355:249-53.](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/7709830)

<sup>3</sup>[A morphological and immunohistological study of the human and rabbit appendix for comparison with the avian bursa. Dev Comp Immunol. 2000 Dec;24(8):797-814.](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/10906392)

Answer (score 8):

The appendix was thought to be vestigial in humans [until recently](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/17936308). Now it appears that, like rabbits, it is a safe harbour for symbiotic bacteria in the intestines.

Source: Bollinger, Barbas, Bush, et al. J Theor Biol. 2007 Dec 21;249(4):826-31. Epub 2007 Sep 7.